cannot resolve method 'databaseBuilder()' in 'Room', Java
I'm trying to build an app with Android using room as a database. While initializing the database I seem to have a problem using the databaseBuilder() method of room. I always get the error: can't find symbol Room.databaseBuilder().
From my perspective, it seems like the databaseBuilder doesn't exist. I already tried to import androidx.room into my project but I still can't find the method.
Is there a reason why it won't find method databaseBuilder in the class room or are there any alternatives?
This is my code:
import android.content.Context;

import androidx.room.Room;
import androidx.room.Database;
import androidx.room.RoomDatabase;

@Database(entities = {Ente.class}, version = 1)
public abstract class DB extends RoomDatabase {

    public abstract dao Dao();

    private static DB _instance;

    public synchronized static DB getInstance(final Context context){
        if (_instance == null){
            synchronized (DB.class){
                if(_instance == null){
                    _instance = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(),
                            DB.class,"Alle_Anzeigen").build();
                }
            }
        }
        return _instance;
    }

}

This is what I mean with "it can't find method Room.databaseBuilder()" :

since someone mentioned it this is my Dao:
import androidx.room.Dao;
import androidx.room.Insert;
import androidx.room.Query;
import androidx.room.Update;

import java.util.List;

@Dao
public interface SomeDao {

    @Query("SELECT *FROM Meine_Platten")
    List<Ente> getAll();

    @Query("SELECT *FROM Meine_Platten WHERE id = :Id")
    Ente getById(int Id);

    @Insert
    void add(Ente ente);

    @Update
    void update(Ente ente);
}

and these are my dependencies:
dependencies {
    implementation libs.appcompat
    implementation libs.material
    implementation libs.activity
    implementation libs.constraintlayout
    implementation libs.androidx.room.gradle.plugin
    implementation libs.androidx.room.runtime
    implementation libs.room.gradle.plugin
    implementation libs.room.compiler
    implementation libs.room.runtime
    annotationProcessor libs.androidx.room.compiler
    testImplementation libs.junit
    androidTestImplementation libs.ext.junit
    androidTestImplementation libs.espresso.core

}


are you sure to add require dependencies of room database if added already then you add this  code
import android.content.Context;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.room.Database;
import androidx.room.Room;
import androidx.room.RoomDatabase;

@Database(entities = {YourClass.class}, version = 1, exportSchema = true)
public abstract class YourDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
    
    public abstract YourDao yourDao();
    
    private static volatile YourDatabase INSTANCE;

    public static YourDatabase getDatabase(final Context context) {
        if (INSTANCE == null) {
            synchronized (YourDatabase.class) {
                if (INSTANCE == null) {
                    INSTANCE = buildDatabase(context);
                }
            }
        }
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    private static YourDatabase buildDatabase(final Context context) {
        return Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(),
                YourDatabase.class, "vault_database")
                .build();
    }
}


this code is working prefect hope this will help you

I already added room dependencies. Can't use your code tho since I'm using java

@Shakeelabbas: The question was about Java code. It is not appropriate to answer using another programming language and suggest they should use AI to convert it to what they need. Please [edit] your answer to direclty use Java.

_instance is of type DB but you try to assign an object of type Builder<DB>.
The following only creates a database builder:
Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(), DB.class,"Alle_Anzeigen");

What you are missing is to actually build the database object using that builder. That's easily remidied though: Append .build().
_instance = Room
        .databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(), DB.class, "Alle_Anzeigen")
        .build();


Also you need to
import androidx.room.Room;


Already tried that but the problem is still that it can't even find the method databaseBuilder. Any idea to why that is?

Are you sure you used import androidx.room.Room; (see the last part of my answer)?

Yes, I did but it still won't work

And what is Room? Can you provide another screenshot while hovering over it?

Room is a class used to build databases with android room. You can find more here: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/Room

Apparently not: What you linked has a databaseBuilder method, wat you have in your code doesn't. So, what is it really?

That's my problem. The Room class I imported to use the databaseBuilder is the one I linked but when I try using Room.databaseBuilder it doesn't exist. I also added the necessary dependency.

There's indeed the call to .build() missing, which causes it to return instanceof RoomDatabase.Builder instead instanceof RoomDatabase.
Those three arguments seem correct, but class-name Dao may clash:
public final annotation class Dao

Which means, you can't do that ...
public abstract dao Dao();


One cannot use @Dao directly. Instead one has to define an interface, from which the code is being generated (Room basically consists of code-annotations and a code-generator). One just has to add annotations and it will generate the whole database abstraction layer.
@Dao
public interface SomeDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM " + Constants.TABLE_SOME_NAME)
    List<SomeItem> getItems();
}

And then reference this instead:
public abstract SomeDao someDao();


I already have a dao interface. My problem is that it can't find the method databaseBuilder in the class Room.

Based on the code you've provided - and as explained, you may have an invalid Dao because you cannot use that name. The RoomDatabase.Builder might fail, when the main abstraction class DB is invalid. The arguments are basically correct, but DB.class nevertheless is at fault, because of that one invalid reference.

As far as I'm concerned there are no problems with my Dao. It just hasn't been used yet. Also I'm using Room.databaseBuilder not RoomDatabase.Builder. Is there any difference in that?

DB.class basically provides the instructions for RoomDatabase.Builder and with nonsensical instructions, it may fail to build. You cannot pretend that it's not in use, when passing it ias argument into the builder and then wonder, why it fails ...

Can you please explain that further. I seem to be missing your point... Where am I passing the Dao as an Argument in the builder? should I remove it from my DB class since it's not really used.
